# Symbolic identification of all the pathways from vertex s to vertex t in a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose that we have a symbolic digraph, meaning that, except the vertex names, edges in the digraph `G` are all `String`.

```
vlst = {1, 2, 3, 4};
elst = {{1, 3} -> a3, {1, 4} -> a4, {2, 1} -> b1, {2, 3} -> 
   b3, {3, 2} -> c2, {4, 2} -> d2};
mat = {{0, 0, a3, a4}, {b1, 0, b3, 0}, {0, c2, 0, 0}, {0, d2, 0, 0}};
G = Graph[{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {a3, a4, b1, b3, c2, d2}, DirectedEdges -> True];
```

An example of my question: Find all the paths from, say, vertex `1` to `2` together with `EdgeWeight` associated with the binary links in the pathway concerned. See the digraph below for the answer: the pathway, `{1->3->2}`, is the only pathway from `1` to `2`, and the associated set of edge weights is `{a3,c2}`. The answer is then: `{{1->3->2},{a3,c2}}`.

I want to find all the pathways in `G` from a vertex `s` to `t` and their associated edge weight sets using a very large symbolic digraph.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[ew]
ew = Module[{g = #, e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ FindPath[##, ∞, All]},
    Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;
```

**Example:**

```
G = Graph[{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}}, 
     EdgeWeight -> {a3, a4, b1, b3, c2, d2}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
     VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

ew[G, 1, 2]
```

> {{{1 -> 4, 4  -> 2}, {a4, d2}}, {{1  -> 3, 3  -> 2}, {a3, c2}}}

```
HighlightGraph[G, ew[G, 1, 2][[All, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is an excellent solution (though my programming knowledge is not sufficient to fully digest it). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tebernus, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: You even found out my mistake in the question:  `{1->3->2}` is not the only pathway as you indicated that `{1->4->2}` is another one. Next time I should be much more careful about the problem statement.

Comment: Some of my questions in MSE have very good answers, and therefore, I use them in my research papers, as well as in the formulation of follow up questions. If I use, for example, your `code` above, should I specifically refer to you as the source of information or should I just use it since your `code` is public information in the site.

Comment: @Teberius, if you scroll to the bottom of the page, in fine print, it says _contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required. rev 2018.10.5.31856_

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that.